Polynomial (Olympiad problem )

$P(x),\ Q(x),\ R(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\ | \  \{deg(P(x)), \ deg(Q(x)), \ deg(R(x))\}\supset\{2,3\}\land P^2(x)+Q^2(x)=R^2(x)$

Prove that one of the polynomials of degree three has three real roots.
By symmetry (WLOG), $deg(P(x))=deg(R(x))=3$ and $deg(Q(x))=2$.
So, $$Q^2(x)= R^2(x)-P^2(x)=(R(x)-P(x))(R(x)+P(x))=A(x)B(x) \implies\{deg(A(x),deg(B(x))\}=\{1,3\}$$
Let $D(x)\in\{A(x),B(x)\}\ |\ deg(D(x))=1$.
Then $D(x)\ | \ Q^2(x)\implies D(x) \ | \ Q(x)\implies $(because $Q(x) $ is a quadratic polynomial),
$Q(x)=\gamma(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\implies E(x)$ is a product of three linear factors and a  constant term, that is $E(x)\in \{A(x),B(x)\}-D(x)$.
I can't figure out how to move on from here. Could someone give me a hint?

Wait, why is $\deg(Q(x)) = 2$?

one of the polynomials ($P(x),R(x),Q(x)$) must have to be of second degree (by hypothesis)(${deg(P(x)),deg(Q(x)),deg(R(x))}\supset{2,3}$)

From $P^2(x)-R^2(x)=Q^2(x)$, we get that $$ (P(x)-R(x))(P(x)+R(x))=Q^2(x) $$
As pointed out in the comments by Calvin Lin, let $P(x)-R(x)$, being linear (WLOG), has to divide $Q^2(x)$ and therefore, $Q(x)$. $Q(x)$, therefore, needs to be of the form $\gamma(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. This puts (WLOG) $$P-R=\gamma_1(x-\alpha),$$ and $$P+R=\gamma_2(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)^2.$$
This gives that $$2P=(x-\alpha)(\gamma_1+\gamma_2(x-\beta)^2),$$
$$2R=(x-\alpha)(\gamma_2(x-\beta)^2-\gamma_1).$$
Depending on the sign of $\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma_2}$, either $P$ or $R$ is real rooted.

True. My oversight. Will fix.

You should also explicitly observe in the above answer, with justification, that $\alpha$, $\beta$ are both real.

Thanks, actually what I needed is contained after the second WLOG.
